# Terminology for Specific Kind of One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: sql-server, terminology, relations

This question regards how a one-to-many row might "belong" to a different row and what exactly to call it.  I might be asking for a term that does not exist.

Please see the below two tables.  Customer and Address form a one-to-many relationship where one Customer might have many addresses.  These Addresses "belong" to a Customer.

| Customer |
| --- |
| CustomerID |
| CustomerName |

| Address |
| --- |
| AddressID |
| CustomerID |
| StreetAddress |
| City |
| State |
| ZIPCode |
| TaxCodeID |

Now notice this table:

| TaxCode |
| --- |
| TaxCodeID |
| TaxPercent |

A single TaxCode could exist for many Addresses (a one-to-many relationship).  But as I see it, Address doesn't "belong" to TaxCode as Address "belongs" to the Customer.  Address is a sort of "child" of Customer whereas Address just has a "link" to TaxCode.  I don't think the database "cares" since I think all the database rules are the same (e.g., foreign keys).  But I'm wondering if specific names exist for these relationships beyond a one-to-many relationship.

In summary, I would like to know what to call the Customer-Address one-to-many relationship vs. the TaxCode-Address one-to-many relationship.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the terms [identifying and non-identifying relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships/762994#762994).  (This comment was posted by [ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9), so the thanks go to him.)